# TypeError: this.Ca is not a function while importing firebase components in my React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

I have a separate file named  "firebase.js" which contains:
I have downloading the firebase package as `npm i firebase`.

```
import firebase from "firebase";
import "@firebase/auth";
import 'firebase/firebase-functions';
// require('firebase/auth');
// import auth from 'firebase/firebase-auth';

 


const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: 
    authDomain:
    projectId:
    storageBucket: 
    messagingSenderId: 
    appId: 
  };

  
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  //export

   const auth= firebase.auth();
  const googleAuthProvider=firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

  export {auth,googleAuthProvider};
```

---

The issue is whenever I'm trying to import the auth from this file and after successful compilation I'm getting this error in the browser.

[image]

I have everything updated to latest versions, whether it is React scripts, npm, everything.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a `new` in this line:

```js
const googleAuthProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
```